# How do I get the "except" to trigger?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, serversocket

We're learning about sockets in Networking and we've been tasked to fill out a template in Python (teacher's using Python2.x while I'm using Python3.x).

```
    # Import socket module
from socket import *

# Create a TCP server socket
#(AF_INET is used for IPv4 protocols)
#(SOCK_STREAM is used for TCP)
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Assign a port number
serverPort = 6789

# Bind the socket to server address and server port
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))

# Listen to at most 1 connection at a time
serverSocket.listen(1) 

# Server should be up and running and listening to the incoming connections
while True:
    print ("Ready to serve...")

    # Set up a new connection from the client
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    # If an exception occurs during the execution of try clause
    # the rest of the clause is skipped
    # If the exception type matches the word after except
    # the except clause is executed
    try:
        # Receive the request message from the client
        message = connectionSocket.recv(4096).decode()
        # Extract the path of the requested object from the message
        # The path is the second part of HTTP header, identified by [1]
        filename = message.split()[1]
        # Because the extracted path of the HTTP request includes 
        # a character '\', we read the path from the second character 
        f = open(filename[1:])
        # Store the entire contenet of the requested file in a temporary buffer
        outputdata = f.read()
        # Send the HTTP response header line to the connection socket
        connectionSocket.send(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n").encode())

        # Send the content of the requested file to the connection socket
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata.encode())):  
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata.encode())  
        connectionSocket.send(("\r\n").encode()) 

        # Close the client connection socket
        connectionSocket.close()

        break

    except IOError:
        # Send HTTP response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send(("HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND\r\n").encode())
        connectionSocket.send(("<html><head></head><body><h1>ERROR. TRY AGAIN</h1></body></html>\r\n").encode())
        # Close the client connection socket
        connectionSocket.close()

        break

#Close the Socket
serverSocket.close()
```

The file I'm reading into it is a .htm file:

```
<html><head><title>HTML Test File</title></head><body><h1>Trying to Get This Frickin' Program to Work</h1></body></html>
```

When I run the program and enter: localhost:6789/TestFile.htm, it prints the file contents over and over and gives me the error message: line 34, indexerror: list index out of range. *edit: break takes care of the error message, but file is still being printed over and over*

What am I doing wrong?

*edit #2: now I'm trying to do the error handling, but it merely states that no data was sent when I type in a file that doesn't exist (i.e. localhost:6789/Test.htm). How do I get the error message to print?*

Comment: You're in a `while True` loop, but you never break out of it.

Comment: I added a "break" at the end of both the "try" and "except." Took care of the error message, but it's still printing the file over and over.

Comment: Please edit that into your main question.

Comment: Edited. The title question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   for i in range(0, len(outputdata.encode())):  
>         connectionSocket.send(outputdata.encode())
> ```

This code:

- encodes the text twice
- loops 121 times (which is the length of the file you posted, encoded as ASCII or UTF-8)
- sends the entire file each of the 121 times

Comment: Tried removing both encodes, but it still prints the message repeatedly.

Comment: Yes.  My note about encoding it twice is the performance of duplicate work.  It would be better to encode once, keep a reference in a local variable, and refer to that variable twice.  However, that is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: PS.: actually, this text will be encoded 122 times, not twice.  : )

Comment: Okay, so I changed the range to (0, 2) and kept "connectionSocket.send(outputdata.encode())". Now it only prints once, but I feel like I took the easy way out.

Comment: Right: the way that code is written, since the entire file is already in memory, I would just remove the loop altogether. Did you create that loop or was it in the teacher's template?

Comment: If I remove the loop it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Did you fill in the `send()` call?  If so, then you discovered that you did not fill in the body of the loop correctly. Analyze the loop; change the body of the loop to use the variable `i` and `send()` correctly.  You are correct that by removing both lines of code nothing is sent; when I said remove the loop I meant the `for` line but not the `send()` line.